# The Windows admin user cannot see the WSL installed on a normal user

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

**ENVIRONMENT:**

**OS**: Windows 11 (but the problem persists since Windows 10)

**WSL**: version: 2

**Distribution**: OpenSUSE (I think it´s not related to the problem)

**THE PROBLEM:**

I installed WSL2 and OpenSUSE with my regular user, and everything is working. Running `wsl -l -v` lists `* openSUSE-Tumbleweed Running 2`

But when I log in with the admin user and run `wsl -l -v`, it says I don't have any distributions installed.

**QUESTION:**

Is this the expected behavior? If I need to use WSL2 as an admin, do I necessarily have to install it and the distribution again on the admin account?

Comment: Can you try `wsl --list --all` ?

Comment: @Philippe As admin, show that has no distributions installed.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. That's the default behavior:

> WSL is designed such that different users can not access other user's Linux files.

Source: Craig Loewen (Program manager at MS): https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4312#issuecomment-514724359